# Firebase and ReactJS - Authentication Using Local Storage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I would like to use localstorage to persist the auth state to avoid slow page content on refreshes. I've read about this elsewhere but unsure how to implement in my case. Could anyone help me work out how to edit the below to make it work please?

This example is similar but I'm not sure how to apply it to my case.

```
import React from 'react';
import { firebase } from '../firebase';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const withAuthentication = (Component) => {
  class WithAuthentication extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        authUser: null,
      };


    }

    getChildContext() {
      return {
        authUser: this.state.authUser,
      };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
        authUser
          ? this.setState(() => ({ authUser }))
          : this.setState(() => ({ authUser: null }));
      });
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <Component />
      );
    }
  }


  WithAuthentication.childContextTypes = {
    authUser: PropTypes.object,
  };

  return WithAuthentication;
}

export default withAuthentication;
```

Comment: Rather than using local storage, you can also just store the user in state in your highest level component like your router. Then you can use context to pass it into whatever component you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks. So I think this withAuthentication.js is my highest level component. It is fine once the page is loaded and I navigate around. But when I refresh the page, it takes a split second to work out whether the user is logged in or not... I hope that makes sense?

Comment: Please do not rely on hacking localStorage. I can tell you with 100% assurance that Firebase Auth will migrate to indexedDB.

Comment: You should never resort to these hacks related to internal implementation as the Firebase Auth team reserves the right to change the internals of it.

Comment: What would you recommend instead bojeil?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy, just replace:

```
this.setState(() => ({ authUser }))
```

with

```
localStorage.setItem('authUser', JSON.stringify(authUser))
```

or

```
localStorage.removeItem('authUser')
```

to remove it

then you can read it:

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authUser'))
```

instead of **this.state.authUser**

and in componentDidMount check if localStorage.getItem('authUser') exists before making the call again.

Comment: Thank you very much. Should I do both, or should I just do localStorage? What is the best practice? Thanks again, I'm trying this out now and will accept once I know it works for me!

Comment: If you are using Redux, you should store it in both localStorage and Redux store, and  you always read it from Redux store, but for persistence you also keep it in the localStorage, because once you refresh the Redux store is gone. So you can use store.subsribe() to initiate the Redux store with the data from localstorage.

Comment: But if you are not, you don't need to use both in this High Order Component, you're good to go only with localStorage

Comment: Thanks Arber, I have done that and it seems to be quicker definitely. However, the localStorage now seems to lag behind a bit. So for example, when I logout, then nothing happens until a page refresh. Do I need to add anything to my withAuthentication component to deal with this if I am using localStorage versus not (I did not have this issue before).

Comment: Ah ok, so the problem is that when you manage localStorage, React doesn't know it changed, so it will not re-render, you can use both then for now, just for the sake of rerendering the component (so you don't have to force a render) with this.forceUpdate()

Comment: Ah ok thanks. Is there some way of doing both in one block of code? I'm struggling with inline statements to do both at once. I have this so far (but can't put the commented pieces back in without breaking it). Thanks again.       authUser
          ? localStorage.setItem('authUser', JSON.stringify(authUser))
          // ? this.setState(() => ({ authUser }))
          :localStorage.removeItem('authUser')
          //: this.setState(() => ({ authUser: null }));

Comment: Ah the this.forceUpdate() works great! Thanks again very much Arber!

Comment: You're welcome, but I wouldn't recommend using this.forceUpdate() however, you've got it working for now, so think about refactoring and improving your code once you're confident :)

Comment: Thanks Arber, you mean it would be better doing the other choice of doing both the localStorage and the setState, over doing the forceUpdate? If so I'll refactor that now!

Comment: Using forceUpdate is not recommended: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate

Comment: Ok thanks! I have implemented the localStorage method alongside the original setState code - thanks again!